# Wordpress back office - search system

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I created a plugin and i have that link **/wp-admin/admin.php?page=il_deposit**

on that link i display data from my database with this code:

```
$_IL_CONN = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(! $_IL_CONN )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$_IL_RESULT_TRAN_LIST = mysqli_query($_IL_CONN,"SELECT * FROM pr_il_transactions");

while($_IL_ROW_TRAN = mysqli_fetch_array($_IL_RESULT_TRAN_LIST)) {

    echo $_IL_ROW_TRAN['il_name'].$_IL_ROW_TRAN['il_surname'].$_IL_ROW_TRAN['il_date'].$_IL_ROW_TRAN['il_status'] .'<br/>';
}
```

i want to make a search, for example i will input the name and my search will search into database throw il_name and display me the result. (i want to search throw all my colums in a specific able and display to the user the result)

thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: why are you connecting using mysqli_connect? why are you not using wordpress functions?

Comment: i was not so familiar with wordpress and because of this i use this, i did something about search but when in the url is adding any parameters i get that u do not have any permission to access that page, i just need a simple search on a specific table. @BhumiShah

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb